# Trying to combine Inner Join and two where statements with a Select Max by date and save result into variable

Tags: sql

I'm trying to use a inner join to combine 3 tables into one and pull 2 variables based on the most recent date of entry in a medical database.

I'm looking to pull the last location a patient was seen at and the doctor at that visit, which I will pass into another command later in my query.  I will save those as @last_location and @doctor_name respectively.  I am using @last_date to try to make a select max to get the last visit only for each given patient.  However, blank values are passing forward on my variables (both @doctor_name and @last_location).  Can anyone help clean this up? Appreciate the help!

My code is:

```
    SELECT @last_location = location_mstr.location_name, @last_date = Substring (CONVERT(CHAR(8), patient_encounter.billable_timestamp, 112), 5, 2) + '/' + Substring (CONVERT(CHAR(8), patient_encounter.billable_timestamp, 112), 7, 2) + '/' + Substring (CONVERT(CHAR(8), patient_encounter.billable_timestamp, 112), 3, 2), @doctor_name = provider_mstr.description
    FROM    
    location_mstr
    INNER JOIN patient_encounter ON location_mstr.location_id = patient_encounter.location_id
    INNER JOIN provider_mstr ON patient_encounter.rendering_provider_id = provider_mstr.provider_id
    Where (patient_encounter.person_id = @person_id) and (@last_date = MAX(@last_date))
```

I also tried changing the last statement based on some threads here to:

```
Where @last_date = (SELECT MAX(@last_date) FROM patient_encounter WHERE patient_encounter.person_id = @person_id)
```

Comment: what kind of DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the where clause of your original query, it looks like you are trying to find the patient_encounter record with the most recent billable_timestamp. The way you are referencing the @last_date variable in the where clause isn't going to do anything.

Instead, you can just get the `TOP 1` most recent row and `ORDER BY` billable_timestamp `DESC` to get what you're looking for.

I also changed the string expression in your select list that sets @last_date to use the SQL `CONVERT` function. You can see a list of date formats that `CONVERT` can do here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

```
SELECT TOP 1
     @last_location = location_mstr.location_name
    ,@last_date = CONVERT(VARCHAR, patient_encounter.billable_timestamp, 1)
    ,@doctor_name = provider_mstr.description
FROM location_mstr
INNER JOIN patient_encounter 
    ON location_mstr.location_id = patient_encounter.location_id
INNER JOIN provider_mstr 
    ON patient_encounter.rendering_provider_id = provider_mstr.provider_id
WHERE patient_encounter.person_id = @person_id
ORDER BY patient_encounter.billable_timestamp DESC
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!  Worked exactly as I had hoped.  Appreciate the help!